# Does React Query replace Redux or other global state managers?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-query

Can I build react project without redux, only using react-query?

Comment: React Query is a server-state library, responsible for managing asynchronous operations between your server and client
Redux, MobX, Zustand, etc. are client-state libraries that can be used to store asynchronous data, albeit inefficiently when compared to a tool like React Query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this page](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/does-this-replace-client-state) in react query's docs where they answer this exact question - hope that helps!